# Portable Class Library HttpUtility.UrlEncode

Tags: windows-phone-7, microsoft-metro, urlencode, portable-class-library

I understand that making web requests is quite well supported in the Portable Class Library. Is there any equivelant of HttpUtility.UrlEncode in the PCL? I need it for Windows Phone and Metro applications.

Comment: HttpUtility.UrlEncode is supported in WP7.

Comment: Not supported when I select Metro and WP7.1 in PCL.

Comment: They live in different locations and binaries, hence, why they are not available.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### WebUtility

In portable class libraries lucky enough to be targeting .NET 4.5 (e.g. Profile7), many of the HttpUtility methods have siblings in [`System.Net.WebUtility`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
using System.Net;

WebUtility.UrlEncode("some?string#");
```

### Potential Warning

While some of the sibling methods appear to be identical to their HttpUtility counterparts, this one has a slight difference between the resulting encodings. `WebUtility.UrlEncode` generates uppercase encodings while `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` generates lowercase encodings.

```
WebUtility.UrlEncode("?") // -> "%3F"
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("?") // -> "%3f"
```

### Make It Backwards Compatible

If you are dependent on your PCL code generating exactly what you would have generated with prior HttpUtility code, you could create your own helper method around this method and regex it.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static string UrlEncodeOldSchool(string value) {
    var encodedValue = WebUtility.UrlEncode(value);
    return Regex.Replace(encodedValue, "(%[0-9A-F]{2})",
                         encodedChar => encodedChar.Value.ToLowerInvariant());
}
```

(Even though this is a simple one, always regex at your own risk.)

Answer (score 35):

Use `Uri.EscapeUriString` and `Uri.EscapeDataString`

The only difference between the two is that `EscapeDataString` also encodes the RFC 2396 reserved characters which includes these characters `;/?:@&=+$`,

It is important to note that neither of these methods encodes the RFC 2396 unreserved characters which includes `-_.!~*'()`
So if you need these encoded then you will have to manually encode them.

Comment: Do you use both or either one of them? The docs for the two is identical except from the name of the method.

Comment: I edited my above answer to explain the differences between the methods.